# MoviePy TextClip set_position not working

Tags: python, imagemagick, moviepy

I am working on my free time on a project that uses:

- MoviePy latest release (1.0.3)
- ImageMagick 7.1.0-53
- Python >=3.8,<4
- Windows 10

The goal is to concatenate clips and for each, I want to show a text at the top left of the screen.

But none of my many tries is concluant (some are listed below). I run out of ideas to test...
The text is always centered at the left.

```py
textclip: TextClip = TextClip(
   some_text,
   method="caption",
   align="center",
   fontsize=60,
   color="white"
)

textclip = textclip.set_position(("left", "top"))
textclip = textclip.set_duration(videoclip.duration)
```

```py
textclip: TextClip = TextClip(
   some_text,
   method="caption",
   align="center",
   fontsize=60,
   color="white"
).set_position(("left", "top")).set_duration(videoclip.duration) # neither set_pos is working
```

Hope i will find some help here, you guys are amazing !

Comment: Due to caption automatic wrapping, Imagemagick removes leading and trailing spaces. So that is not possible.  You could use periods or hyphens in place of spaces as the best alternative

Comment: You answered the wrong question, I admit it is confusing at first sight. Thx for your advice, I will take a look at periods and hyphens

Comment: Sorry about answering the wrong question. I must have clicked on the wrong link.